# How to get text value of an element by using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, appium, ui-automation

I'm using node.js for UI automation with appium and I need to get a text value from elements. Did anyone do this before?

Comment: There is a good chance this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

pure node.js cannot do something like this because node.js is the back-end technology.

you need to use some libs, selenium, robot framework to test.

the scenario will be like

1. open brower
2. do somthing, e.g., fill text box, click button
3. get result from html dom

Comment: He uses appium as stated in the tags

Answer (score -1):

Why Using Node.js? Just Use Simple Javascript

```
 var x = document.getElementById ("your input id").value;
```